# Ordinary Least Squares: How to find the two features that jointly minimize mean squared error given individual coefficients?

Tags: linear-regression

Say you are given $d$ features with $N$ data points and trying to predict target $y$.

You first try to fit an ordinary least squares model to each feature (+ bias term), that is finding $(\beta_{0i}, \beta_{1i})$ (slope, bias term) for all feature $1\leq i\leq d$.

If you want to find the two features that **jointly** minimize the mean squared error, is there any way to re-use the individual coefficients you computed earlier? Or do you have to fit a model for every bivariate combination of the $d$ features?

Comment: Signs can change from the one-variable case to the two-variable case, so you would have to fit a new equation for every pair of predictors. What I want to know, however, is what you’re doing. Are you trying to do some kind of feature selection?

Comment: This is more of a brain teaser than an actual practical question. I was wondering if one could maybe re-use the covariance between the features and the target variable, computed during the first step, to sort of alleviate the computational cost of fitting a new equation to every pair of predictors.